# Start keras learning parallel to application

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras

I have an application running with a model of keras which I want to learn with `model.fit`. Since in this application other functionalities are included I would like to use my application during the time its learning the model.

So I started to build a new Thread for the model.fit function. Here my problems begin:

One method in class abc should call the method learn in class def.

In this class the other class with method is called

```
class abc:
   def execute_learn(self):
       tf_session = K.get_session()  
       tf_graph = tf.get_default_graph()

       learning_results = thread_file.def(some_data, model, tf_session, tf_graph)
       learning_results.start()
       learning_results.join()
```

In this class `.fit()` is executed

```
class def(Thread):
   def __init__(self, some_data, model, tf_session, tf_graph):
      self.some_data = some_data
      self...

   def run(self):
      tf_session = self.tf_session
      tf_graph = self.tf_graph

      with tf_session.as_default():
          with tf_graph.as_default():
              self.learn(self.some_data, self.model)

   def learn(self, some_data, model):
      model.compile
      model.fit(...)
```

This "works", since I dont get any error messages anymore (especially tensorflow ones), but my whole application is blocked by the execution of `model.fit()`.

Maybe I did something wrong with multithreading it, hope someone can help me :)

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I found the mistake for this problem: its the `.join()` call which I had in the last line of "class abc".

I still have some other problems which are tensorflow/keras specific, this problem is solved.

EDIT: changed class for clarification

Comment: Where is the `LearningController` code? If it's the class, it doesn't have a name, and its `__init__` method doesn't accept all the arguments you're using.

Comment: I can't understand your control flow from the snippets you posted. Are you having a basic threading issue? In other words, if you substitute `model.compile` and `model.fit`with `time.sleep(100)` can you do some work other than sleeping?